About the acceptance of Newton's light experiment
I originally posted this question in History Stack Exchange, but I was recommended to post it here instead.
My question starts with the following statement from a book I'm reading

"Moreover, repetition of a well-established experience could give results that made it be called into question: an important example is that of Newton's light scattering experiment, which initially failed in France, Italy and the Netherlands because of the inferior quality of the prisms used"

I found this fact quite amusing and I decided to keep searching about it. However, I didn't find a lot of information regarding the trouble that scientists had replicating this experiment due to the quality of the prisms. In fact, I just found one article that mentions it:

Within a week, Hooke fired off his first attack on Newton's report, and other critics—both at home and abroad—rapidly followed suit. They were dissatisfied not only with the difficulties of replicating his results, but also with his methodological arguments, and a couple of months later Newton wrote to Oldenburg admitting that he should have given fuller experimental details. The status of the experiment that he claimed to be crucial continued to be challenged. Should that one single trial override the implications of many others? When competitors announced they could split Newton's supposedly basic rays into ones of different colours, he retorted that if his rivals could not replicate his work, they were using the wrong type of prism.

In this paragraph, at least for me, it seems to picture it as more of a "quick response" of Newton to his objectors, rather than an "empirical fact", if you will.
My question is if there's any more material I could read where it definitely states that the prisms used were worse, therefore the experiments failed to reproduce Newton's results.
(The book I cited is Historia de la ciencia, by Carlos Solís and Manuel Sellés. It's in Spanish and I couldn't find it translated to English, so I had to do it myself to ask here).

Your source cites Schaffer, Glass works: Newton's prism and the uses of experiment, which gives a very detailed account of the controversy over Newton's experiment crucis and the role of prisms in it. It was not all prisms, although their quality played a role, but that was a simplified redux for the public promoted by Voltaire and Co. in the 18th century. Newton was also vague both in the description of his instruments and procedures, and in the interpretation of what his experiment crucis was supposed to demonstrate.

@Conifold this reads like an answer...
